# SAP ABAP delete a workflow

Tags: workflow, abap

I have a running workflow which is in an endless loop.

Now I want to delete/cancel this workflow.
In which Transaction can I do that?

Comment: did the below answer help?

Comment: @iPirat not really beacause i cant delete it in the transaction SWIA

Comment: you shouldnt try to delete it, try to stop it. (I did an update to the answer below)

Comment: Thank you for your update. I choose the workflow and klicked on the button `Complete Manually` but there I get the message `The status of the work item does not allow the function manual completion. Please cancel the current action using the command cancel.` So I Went to de Menu->Eidt->cancel there I got the message `function abort`....

Comment: Of you find ist in SWIA, use button “protocol” or similar, there switch to technical view, find out the workitem id of the root of the workflow instance. => use “manual stop” on that one in the main view of SWIA

Comment: @iPirat I got it. I had to get the parent ID and then search again in the SWIA transaction and clicked `manually completed`. Now it works :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just updated the answer below. with the additional info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to transaction `SWIA` and find the workflow instance. One of the Action buttons is to cancel this workflow instance.

**Update:** just checked, the button is called "Manuell beenden" (I assume "Stop manually" or similar in English)

BTW, you should apply that button to the root node of the workflow instance (type WS...)

If you find your workitem in `SWIA`, use button "protocol" or similar, then switch to technical view, find out the workitem id of the root of the workflow instance. => use "manual stop" on that one in the main view of `SWIA`.